# How can I stop the a jMonkeyEngine game?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I want to quit the game, if 2 values are higher than 3. I want to put in in here:

```js
        if(player.getWorldTranslation().y > 3){
            if(player.getWorldTranslation().z > 3){
                 
            }
```

I guess its in the documentation, but I still could´nt find any answer after 10minutes searching.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: `System.exit(1);`

Comment: call `stop()` from your class that extends from `Application`; https://jmonkeyengine.github.io/wiki/jme3/intermediate/simpleapplication.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best(if you need to stop the game and not the program):

```
static Main app;//Put the app variable global and static
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
   app = new Main();
   app.start();
}
...

if(player.getWorldTranslation().y > 3){
    if(player.getWorldTranslation().z > 3){
        app.Stop(1);
        //System.exit(1);//if you need close the entire program;
    }
```

Comment: Should be `app.stop(1);`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/stopping-a-game/19332) a link to quitting the game. You could also use `System.exit(int)`. Either way it works.